# Creation of a Target Variable

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

So i'm new to machine learning and data science, i've been looking tutorials and i'm working on self made project at the moment and i'm having an analysis paralysis with the data preprocessing portion. I think i'm over complicating this but here are some questions I have.

So for example, I have survey data from people about a store and I hope to use this data to help them find out whether or not they're willing to spend money on the store.

I have things like median household income, age, gender, whether or not they're happy, but for what I want my target variable to be would be something along the lines of "Would this person buy stuff from this store," this obviously isn't in the data set. How would I go about creating this as my target variable? Is this feasible to do in the first place?

All tutorials online have their target variable already in the data set so they can train on it, would creating the target variable with 0 values be feasible? Would I need to create logic to fill the values from already established predictor variables?

Comment: Do you have data about whether people have bought from the store in the past?

Comment: I do not have that, no, it's mostly just general life questions.

Comment: I have the same problem, however in my case I have the records to create the target variable but in other dataset. So what I mean is that I receive all the information from a survey, however in this dataset is not the target variable, the target variable comes from other csv file. Could I make a Supervised ML if I set the target variable that comes from other file?
How could affect this when putting the model in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a target variable, you cannot do supervised machine learning. After all, you don't know whether any of these people would shop at the store or not, so any prediction your model produces will be a complete guess, and you won't have any way to tell whether it's right or not.

If you just want to do a toy problem, you could build a synthetic target variable based on some input features like income or gender. But that relationship will be entirely contrived however you see fit, and your predictive model should just recover those relationships to arrive at a model that's pretty similar to however you generated the data in the first place. This can be useful to get experience in the mechanics of just running some methods, but you shouldn't base any domain inferences on your output, since you are the one that's defining true model you're attempting to learn. Toy problems such as this can be useful for benchmarking different methods, though, since you know exactly what the true underlying model is. You know the target variable is, in fact, predictable in the first place, and exactly which features it depends upon.

Comment: So would you say unsupervised machine learning to get this estimation of whether or not they would buy from this store would fit better?

Comment: @jcmgs Unsupervised learning will identify if there are any natural groupings of individuals in your data, and how many of those groups there are, but what those groups represent is open to interpretation. You might hypothesize that a high-income, high-impulsiveness shopper group would be likely to buy from the store, for example, but without any data to back that up, it's just a guess. You don't seem to have any data on whether people actually buy from the store or not, so you have no means of evaluating your estimate of the likelihood of that happening.

Comment: @jcmgs Any method that says something like shopper A is 30% likely to buy and shopper B is 90% likely to buy (or will/won't buy) can't be evaluated, since you don't know if shoppers A and B actually did buy anything. Your model could output numbers entirely unrelated to reality, and you'd never know.

Comment: So would a classification be better to fit, delegate someone to be either a buyer or not a buyer? Would the same logic behind the threshold to make that decision still apply there if it was classification instead of regression?

Comment: @jcmgs It doesn't really matter if it's regression or classification, you don't have a means of evaluation. Your model could say a shopper is 90% likely to buy, or is in the class "Will buy", but you can't tell if it's right or not. Your model might classify everyone correctly, or get everyone wrong, and you cannot tell which it is. What is your goal in this analysis? If you want to find out what variables predict a Buy, you're out of luck. If you want to benchmark different methods against known data, a synthetic target is appropriate.

Comment: The former is what I was hoping for, but since there is no history of a column like a response to advertising or something like that, it wouldn't be feasible. That's understandable, thank you.